# Set i'th value of kernel module array with command line arguments

Tags: command-line, kernel-modules, array

Given a kernel module `arraymod.c` with the following array declaration:

```
static int myintArray[2] = { -1, -1 };
static int arr_argc = 0;
module_param_array(myintArray, int, &arr_argc, 0000);
MODULE_PARM_DESC(myintArray, "An array of integers");
```

I know that `myintArray` will be initialized to `[-1, -1]`

When inserting the module, I can do the following things:

```
sudo insmod arraymod.ko myintArray=5       // myintArray=[5,-1]
sudo insmod arraymod.ko myintArray=5,11    // myintArray=[5,11]
```

Is there any way to set an arbitrary position without setting the rest? Something like

`sudo insmod arraymod.ko myintArray[1]=12   // myintArray=[-1,12]`

Comment: nope. some kernel modules may let you skip over array entries you want to leave at default with a comma.  e.g. `sudo insmod arraymod.ko myintArray=,11` but that's dependent on the module itself and how it interprets an empty arg.